# computing a limit

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I couldn't compute this limit:

[image]

it should be -3. I couldn't find the analytic way to compute it.

Comment: If this question is even about *Mathematica*, please add the *Mathematica* code you have tried in a copyable format.

Answer (score 3):

*Mathematica* can find your limit. I typed the following

```
Limit[(1 - Cos[Sin[x]^5])/((E^x^4 - 1) (Sin[x^2] - x^2)), x -> 0]
```

The output is `-3`.

Comment: I'm having trouble in finding the technique to calculating this limit

Comment: Not sure if this is the right forum for that. You could try `WolframAlpha["Limit[(1-Cos[Sin[x]^5])/((E^x^4-1) (Sin[x^2]-x^2)),x->0]"]` and view Show steps on the right hand corner

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [L'Hôpital's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule) 
 rule repeatedly.

Here I have used Mathematica to do it:

Define your numerator and denominator

```
num = (1 - Cos[Sin[x]^5]);
den = ((E^x^4 - 1) (Sin[x^2] - x^2));
```

Find the first instance when the derivative gives non-zero value. In this case it happens at the 10th derivative.

```
num0 = SelectFirst[Table[D[num, {x, j}] /. x -> 0, {j, 30}], # != 0 &]
den0 = SelectFirst[Table[D[den, {x, j}] /. x -> 0, {j, 30}], # != 0 &]
```

The limiting value is -3

```
 N[num0/den0]
  (*-3.*)
```